# ARKit No Camera - XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit

I'm trying to test a project with ARKit on XCode. Whenever I build the project, I can see my 3D Model by not the camera feed.

I tried the AR demo XCode project by Apple. When I built this project, I still received no camera feed. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: What device do you have running the apps?

Answer (score 0):

Please check iOS version of your device
You have to run app in device which having iOS 11 or later

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are using one of following devices:

- iPhone 6s and 6s Plus
- iPhone 7 and 7 Plus
- iPhone SE
- iPad Pro (9.7, 10.5 or 12.9), 1st generation and 2nd generation
- iPad (2017)
- iPhone 8 and 8 Plus
- iPhone X
- iPhone Xs, iPhone XR and iPhone Xs Max

ARKit supported only with devices that uses A9, A10 and A11 chips and higher.